# Azure Media Services Job status webhook notifications

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-media-services

I have a nodejs based application that I'm running on azure. It's basically a CRUD app for video files. I'm currently able to upload and create jobs with Azure Media Services via the REST api (https://app-name.restv2.westus2-2.media.azure.net/api/Jobs). However I am unable to get any job status or resulting metadata. Ideally I will create a thumbnail and then send the assetID back to my servers along with the sources metadata and from there I can determine which other output types I'd like to create.

I've attempted setting up an Event Subscription via a webhook endpoint in the "Events" blade of my instance of media services on the azure portal website. The way I understand it I should be getting https POST requests whenever there is a status update?

I know that I need to validate the endpoint as per the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/security-authentication#validation-details
And have done so successfully.

Am I missing something? I can see and successfully log the initial validation query from Events but never get another event of any type.

Any info you can toss my way is MUCH appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use webhooks, please follow the steps in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-dotnet-check-job-progress-with-webhooks) document. The Event (Grid) notifications work only with our v3 APIs which are currently in preview. And in v3, we have not completed the work to return Job details - you would only get notified of the final state of the Job.

Comment: Great thanks for making that clear. I was conflating two different versions of the API it seems. I found an older post that describes the v2 job/task creation with a webhook endpoint. I had to create a separate notification endpoint via the AZ CLI and then provide that notification endpoint id to the job. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cc69a85f-74b0-4d52-8e69-629ff5007169/create-an-encoding-job-with-jobnotificationsubscriptions-by-using-rest-api-got-a-response-with-400?forum=MediaServices